# Oracle SQL - Sum and group data by daily, weekly and monthly. (With missing date, week, and month)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get total amount of transactions group by daily, weekly and monthly.
What i've tried gave me the result I expected but not giving the date or week or month if there is no transactions on the particular period.

```
Daily

SELECT to_char(tran_timestamp, 'YYYY/MM/DD') FROM TRANSACTIONS
WHERE
TRAN_STATUS = 'SUCCESS' AND
tran_timestamp  >= TO_DATE('2019/07/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
AND tran_timestamp <= TO_DATE('2019/09/30','yyyy/mm/dd')
GROUP BY to_char(TRAN_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
ORDER BY to_char(TRAN_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY/MM/DD');

Weekly

SELECT to_char(tran_timestamp, 'YYYY/MM/W') FROM TRANSACTIONS
WHERE
TRAN_STATUS= 'SUCCESS' AND
tran_timestamp  >= TO_DATE('2019/07/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
AND tran_timestamp <= TO_DATE('2019/09/30','yyyy/mm/dd')
GROUP BY to_char(TRAN_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY/MONTH/W')
ORDER BY to_char(TRAN_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY/MONTH/W');

Monthly

SELECT to_char(tran_timestamp, 'YYYY/MM/MM') FROM TRANSACTIONS
WHERE
TRAN_STATUS = 'SUCCESS' AND
tran_timestamp  >= TO_DATE('2019/07/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
AND tran_timestamp <= TO_DATE('2019/09/30','yyyy/mm/dd')
GROUP BY to_char(TRAN_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY/MONTH/MM')
ORDER BY to_char(TRAN_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY/MONTH/MM');
```

For an example:
Monthly result

```
Date     Total amt
2019/09  100
2019/07  500
```

But i need the result like :

```
Date     Total amt
2019/09  100
2019/08  0
2019/07  500
```

Comment: This kind of question gets asked frequently, did you try to search? What you need is often referred to as a calendar table

Comment: Instead of `GROUP BY to_char(TRAN_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY/MONTH/W')` or `GROUP BY to_char(TRAN_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY/MONTH/MM')` better use `GROUP BY TRUNC(TRAN_TIMESTAMP, 'MM')` and `GROUP BY TRUNC(TRAN_TIMESTAMP, 'IW')`, `GROUP BY TRUNC(TRAN_TIMESTAMP)`. Check [ROUND and TRUNC Date Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions271.htm#SQLRF52058), most likely '`W'` or `'WW'` is not what you actually like to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate `all dates` between your start and end date and join it with the result of your query.

Following query will give daily total amount. You need to change `group by`, `order by` and `select clause` if you want to get weekly and monthly result.

```
select all_dates.d as tran_timestamp, 
       sum(your_query.amt) as total_amt
 from
    (select date '2019-07-01' + level - 1 as d
       from dual
     connect by level <= (date '2019-09-30' - date '2019-07-01' ) + 1) all_dates 
Left join
    (SELECT trunc(tran_timestamp) as tran_timestamp , amt
       FROM TRANSACTIONS
      WHERE TRAN_STATUS = 'SUCCESS' 
        AND tran_timestamp  >= TO_DATE('2019/07/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
        AND tran_timestamp <= TO_DATE('2019/09/30','yyyy/mm/dd')) your_query
On (all_dates.d = tran_timestamp)
Group by all_dates.d
order by all_dates.d;
```

Cheers!!